# Esign : Position signature block to specific postion using v6 api PHP

Tags: php, api, adobe, echosign

I have tried changing the postion of default signature added by adobe esign at the end of document. I have tried using

```
" 'contentType' => 'SIGNATURE_BLOCK'    "
```

in fields property for the api  : api/rest/v6/agreements/{agreementId}/formFields . But it doesn't work with "SIGNATURE_BLOCK" contentType and field is not shown in pdf in required location.

So adding "contentType"  parameter with any value 'SIGNATURE_BLOCK' or 'SIGNATURE' or 'SIGNER_NAME' or 'SIGNER_FIRST_NAME' or 'SIGNER_LAST_NAME' or 'SIGNER_INITIALS' or 'SIGNER_EMAIL' doesn't add  fields to document.

Here is link from adobe https://helpx.adobe.com/sign/kb/formfields-option-is-not-available-in-v6-of-rest-api-adobe-sign.html , i have used as reference.

Please Help , how to use the api appropriately .

```
Here is the PHP array i have used :
             ['fields' =>
                    [
                        [
                            'locations' =>
                            [
                                [
                                    'pageNumber' => 1,
                                    'top' => 600,
                                    'left' => 300,
                                    'width' => 111,
                                    'height' => 30,
                                ]
                            ],
                            'name' => 'test_es_:signer:signature',
                            'inputType' => 'SIGNATURE',
                            'recipientIndex' => 1,
                            'alignment' => 'RIGHT',
                            "required" => 1,
                            'contentType' => 'SIGNATURE_BLOCK'
                        ],

                    ]
             ]
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I have kept  contentType out of locations Array

Comment: And i guess you encode it to json before use it right?

Comment: yes , exactly i encode it .  and if i omit contentType , it works with default contentType='DATA' in response.

Comment: Hi, i'm in the same situation. How do you fixed?

Comment: Hi, I confirm using 'contentType' => 'DATA' it works. But i don't know how to remove GENERATED signature block by default at the end of document. any suggest?

Comment: Did anyone find an answer to this? I confirmed that this all still works but using DATA does not remove the signature field from the bottom of the document. Any help is appreciated.